# Abstract uses of Python result in TypeError

Tags: cpython

Using the below code as an example:

```
def inner(a, b):
    return (a, b)

def outer(func, *args, **kwargs):
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
```

When `outer(inner, 1, b=2)` is executed it returns the correct value `(1, 2)`.

How can the same function be called with the argument `a` passed as a `kwargs` and argument `b` passed as an `arg`? That is: `outer(inner, 1, a=2)`.

Running `outer(inner, 1, a=2)` raises the exception: `TypeError: inner() got multiple values for argument 'a'`.

How can functions be wrapped so that arguments can be passed "out of order"?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you *can't* do that.  Positional arguments always come before keyword arguments.  How would it know that your 1st argument is supposed to be the 2nd parameter?  I guess you could do `outer(inner, b=1, a=2)`, would that work?

Comment: While it can be done, it is not simple, and also probably not a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could `inspect` the method and obtain the name of the parameters. You then generate the list of the remaining parameters that you all pass explicitly. Like:

```
>>> list(inspect.signature(inner).parameters)
['a', 'b']
```

So you can generate a list of remaining parameters:

```
import inspect

def outer(func, *args, **kwargs):
    remain = list(par for par in inspect.signature(func).parameters if par not in kwargs)
    kwargs.update(zip(remain,args))
    return func(**kwargs)
```

So it will *ignore* all variables that are stated explicitly and then `zip` the remaining *non-named* variables (here the remaining one is `b`) with the *unnamed values*.

Note that if you thus specify

```
def inner3(a,b,c):
    return (a,b,c)
```

that if you specify `outer(inner,1,2,a=4)`, the unnamed variables need to be specified as `(b,c)` (that order) so `b = 1` and `c = 2`. If you specify `outer(inner,1,2,b=4)` then `a = 1` and `c = 2`. Furthermore if you specify two parameters, the unnamed one will here be unified with the remaining one, so `outer(inner,1,a=2,c=4)` will result in `b=1`.

That being said I think it is **not a good idea** to do this. The behavior is hard to understand so people will tend to make mistakes. There are probably good reasons why the designers of Python did not choose to support this feature at the interpreter level. Of course there can be (good) reasons why you want to do this, but please think twice before doing so.

Comment: Thank you for the clever approach! Absolutely agree with you about this being a double edged sword